# Excel displays horizontal information incorrectly in graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have the graph below:

[image]

This graph should display a range of information on the Mohs and Knoops Hardness Scales

The Moh's data should be ranging from around 1.25-10, and knoop information from around 0-7000

Displayed on the graph, it should be 0-7000 on the X axis, and 0-10 on the Y axis. It seems to display the Y axis fine, but the X axis shows around 1-127 ish. Ive checked the formatting for the axis and it doesnt appear to be using logarithmic scale or anything, so Im not sure why its doing this.

The graph itself seems to be displayed how I want, but the values on the bottom are incorrect.

I tried manually setting the horizontal scale to 7000 and it scales down the Data for some reason??? It makes no sense.

[image]

I would like to attach a copy of the spreadsheet but it appears this site only allows images for some reason.

Comment: Yes, this site only allows images. Please edit you post and add an image of your data layout.

Comment: You can edit you question to include your data as text which can be copy/pasted, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), and you can upload an Excel workbook to some public sharing site (eg OneDrive, DropBox, Google Drive) and then post a link here.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a line chart, where the x axis is a category axis. Change the chart to be an XY Scatter chart, which plots numeric data on the X axis. Make sure to select the correct data ranges for the X and the Y axis data.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to re-sort the data on X-axis in **ascending** order may help... And as teylyn mentioned *change the chart to XY Scatter* which plots data on the **X-axis**, as XY Scatter charts are used for data that has no inherent order. hope that works.